# Is there a way to accomodate a cassette fan coil when the joists are too close?

Tags: hvac, ceiling, ceiling-fan, heat-pump

Is it possible to accommodate a cassette fan coil in the ceiling when the joists are too close?

Or maybe I should ask: are there ways to reinforce around a cut in the joists?

### Context

I'm trying to retrofit my home with a heat pump which requires a registered installer so I've been asking a few contractors and have been getting a wide range of answers. Some say they can do it, others say my joists are probably too close to install something like this.

This is the type of 9 kBTU sized cassette like I want installed:

[image]

I live in a town house, and the cassettes would be for the top floor, where there is sufficient attic space for the height of the unit.

This is what my attic looks like:

[image]

Comment: Is your roof a truss system (lots of interconnected struts with metal plates at the joints) or traditional rafters?

Comment: Good question @AloysiusDefenestrate it looks like a truss system to me? I've just attached an image of my attic space.

Comment: so you want to cut  in those trusters

Comment: Measurements would be a good first step, before asking.  Measure the size of the fan and the space between joists/trusses.  Most buildings have standard spacing and imagine those fans are made for it.  Off hand from the picture(bad to guess from) maybe 24 inch OC which should give you about 22 1/2 free space between

Comment: The fan measurements should be listed on the web page, if you do not have it yet.

Comment: Good question @crip659. I understand that my joists may accommodate the cassette fan, but my question is more general so that if the contractor finds there is no space, I want to be able to find a work-around or hire another contractor to make the accommodations. Like is there a way to brace the joist over or around the cassette fan?

Comment: For up to removing 1/2 inch(1/4 inch on two joists) should not be problem.  For removing about half the joists then need extra support by sistering more wood to the joists.  Removing a whole section of joist, will probably want an engineer.  Should probably have an engineer for sistering also, to be safe.

Comment: Gotchya @crip659, exactly the answer I was looking for. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it!